# Stucked on SP on SQL with Cursor

Tags: t-sql, database-cursor

I'm a little stuck on a Stored Procedure on SQL where I got a Cursor. When I call it from my .net application, It works well until enter to the cursor and give me this error: **"The cursor is READ ONLY."** My little Cursor is this:

```
DECLARE CabCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ArtId from #Res 
WHERE TipoRegistro = 1 order by TipoRegistro, Año, NumSemana, ArtCodigo
FOR UPDATE OF ArtStockInicial, ArtStockFinal
OPEN CabCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM CabCursor into @idArt
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    exec @stockInicial = CalcularExistenciasParaArticulo 
        @idarticulo= @idArt,
        @idalmacen= @pAlmacenId, 
        @fechaHasta= @pFechaDesde;

    exec @stockFinal = CalcularExistenciasParaArticulo 
        @idarticulo= @idArt,
        @idalmacen= @pAlmacenId, 
        @fechaHasta= @pFechaHasta;

    update #Res
    set ArtStockInicial= @stockInicial, ArtStockFinal = @stockFinal
    where current of CabCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CabCursor into @idArt
END
CLOSE CabCursor
DEALLOCATE CabCursor
```

I'm a little stuck because I don't see where and why It gives me the error. I hope u can explain me that where or how can I fix it.

Thanks for all your time.

**30/07/2020 [Edited]
This problem has resolved correctly**

Comment: I suppose the real question is, do you need to use a `CURSOR`. Would you, perhaps, be better off changing your procedure to handle a table type parameter?

Comment: I need to use Cursor because It's just a specific requirement. Could You help me with that READ ONLY problem?